# Capistrano + whenever + db database.yml not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, whenever

I'm trying to run Capistrano 2.15.5 with Whenever 0.8.4 and Ruby 2.0.0

I've added

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

to the end of my **deploy.rb** file and it always run:

```
/releases/20150910075216 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab 
app_name --set environment=production --roles db
```

and fails wth

```
 No such file or directory - 
/releases/20150910075216/config/database.yml
```

because **database.yml** is in folder **/shared/** anyways I don't need the db -

**how to get rid of --roles db in the capistrano command?**

I have

```
server("my_server", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true)
```

because I need the **:db** for other scripts.

Thanks for help!

David

Answer (score 0):

You should set `linked_files` Symlink linked files `database.yml` as following in `deploy.rb` for `capistrano 3`

```
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')
```

Or you can do Symlink manually for older version.

```
desc "Make symlink for database yml"
task :symlink do
   run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

Comment: Hi @David add custom task for you, you can try this. You can user this at `after deploy` hook.